# After assigning a value to a string. When multiplying, why does it multiply the string and not the value assigned to it?

Tags: python

[image]

python assigning values to string. Value does not mulitply when multiplying the string

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a moment to read the help center- https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 2):

> After assigning a value to a string

No. You have not assigned a value to a string. You have assigned a value to a *variable*. Strings are still sequences of characters, and typing `vanilla` into an `input` prompt will always give you a string `'vanilla'` representing that sequence of characters, not whatever value you assigned to the variable named `vanilla`.

Instead of variables, use a dict mapping flavor names to prices, and index the dict:

```
flavor_prices = {
    'vanilla': 2.5,
    'mango': 3.5,
    'strawberry': 4.0,
    'chocolate': 5.0,
}

flavor = input('What flavor do you want?')
quantity = int(input('How many do you want?'))

print('The total cost is', flavor_prices[flavor] * quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should just copy/paste your code as mentioned in the comments.And not post image/screen-shot.

Since it were couple of lines, I made an attempt to type it down for you.
I just tried one variable, but its working fine for me.

You need to post exact error you are having and exact code you are trying.
Are you using python 3.x? For me on 2.x it works fine.

Alternately, you may want to wrap `input` as `float`.

```
Flavour = float(input("what flavour do you want?"))
```

Part of your code:

```
vanilla = float(2.50)

Flavour = input("what flavour do you want?")
Quantity = int(input("How many do you want?"))

print("The total cost is $",Flavour*Quantity)

Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
what flavour do you want?vanilla
How many do you want?2
('The total cost is $', 5.0)
```

Answer (score -1):

a = "car"
a*2
carcar

Because how do I multiply words by a number? You return the string that many times it was multiplied.

b = "2" this a string not an integer or a float before if multiply it I need to covert the string using int() or float()
Int(b) * 2 =4